# User Access to a Folder on File Server

Tags: permissions

We have one File Server running Windows Server 2008 R2. We have different folders on File Server like HR, Operations, Accounts, Finance, Sales ec cetra. User A is a new user and he/she wants to access HR folder and everything that's in there. On User A's desktop, when I click on Run and typed: \fileserver (the name of the File Server) and one Window pop-up asking me for Username and Password. I gave Administrator as Username and Admin password in Password field and hit OK. I get an access to File Server. Now, I dragged HR folder from the server onto the user A's desktop. User A has now access to HR folder. But the problem is now user A can also access other files on File Server as well apart from HR. User A now can access Accounts, Finance, Sales etc. Can you please help me to limit user'a access to HR only.

PS: User A is only given permission to HR. Permission is properly given including share and ntfs.

Thanks and looking forward to hearing from you guys. Cheers..

Comment: Admin? Ugh. Please check how the network is set up first. If in a domain then create a group 'HR people' and only give access to the HR folder to people in that group.(NOT individual people, not admin). Then add all HR people to that group.  Next the user can log in on  his/her desktop and access the folder with her/his regular domain account.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your question is related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/520537/give-access-to-a-subdirectory-without-giving-access-to-parent-directories) (see accepted answer). It discusses the permissions needed on a parent folder to allow a user to get at a child folder that they have permissions for.

On the other hand, your question may simply be prompted by you logging in to the server as the administrative user which is absolutely *not* what you want to do. Having set up the correct permissions the user's credentials should be passed directly from their Windows machine and you should not need to enter any credentials. If you are asked for credentials, first of all think about why it is happening (and possibly change the server permissions) and then always enter the user's credentials.